# How can I extract a string starting in ":" from the end of another string?

Tags: javascript

I have javascript strings with contents like this:

```
" xxxxxxx -errors follow: xxxxxxxxx failed validation xxxxx : yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy "
```

How can I extract just the yyyyy from my string? Note I want to get the text between the last ":" and the end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s = " xxxxxxx -errors follow: xxxxxxxxx failed validation xxxxx : yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy "
s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(':')+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.prototype.split()` and get the last one in the resultant array:

```
var a = " xxxxxxx -errors follow: xxxxxxxxx failed validation xxxxx : yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy ".split(':');
console.log(a[a.length - 1]); // " yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy "
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression like this:

```
/:\s*([^:]*)\s*$/
```

This will match a literal `:` followed by zero or more whitespace characters, followed by zero or more of any characters *other than* `:`, captured in group 1, followed by zero or more whitespace characters and the end of the string.

For example:

```
var input = " xxxxxxx -errors follow: xxxxxxxxx failed validation xxxxx : yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy ";
var output = input.match(/:\s*([^:]*)\s*$/)[1];
console.log(output); // "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `string.lastIndexOf()` method:

```
var text = " xxxxxxx -errors follow: xxxxxxxxx failed validation xxxxx : yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy ";
var index = text.lastIndexOf(":");
var result = text.substring(index + 1); // + 1 to start after the colon
console.log(result); // yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str=" xxxxxxx -errors follow: xxxxxxxxx failed validation xxxxx : yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy "

var arr=new Array(); arr=str.split(":");

var output=arr[arr.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s=" xxxxxxx -errors follow: xxxxxxxxx failed validation xxxxx : yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy "

s= s.substr(s.lastIndexOf(':')+1);
```